# select distinct and autoincrement field in select query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table Product
with

```
ProductNo ProductDetail UniqueiD(Primarykey)
L1234      ProductA        1
L1234      ProductB        2
L1234      ProductC        3
M1234      ProductD        4
M1234      ProductE        5
```

So i need a select query that will display distinct product no with ids for displaying in p-listbox.
say

```
Name  code
L1234  1
M1234  2
```

How do i achieve this?
Thanks

Comment: _"product no with ids"_ What does that mean? And what is the source "code"? Typically with a dropdown list box, one might display a string (like name or code or product number) but need some unique value specifically associated with the selected item (or items). Your "codes" don't appear to have any relationship to values in any table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method is:

```
select distinct name, dense_rank() over (order by name)
from product;
```

That said, I would probably use `group by`:

```
select name, row_number() over (order by name) as code
from product
group by name;
```